# Redis function not defined - Python

Tags: python, redis

Importing redis into python works fine. But initializing by Redis function is not working.

[image: Redis]

Comment: Copy/pasting the traceback would be more helpful than a screenshot of the error.  Also, what does `import redis; print(redis.__file__)` show?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install

```
sudo pip install redis
```

OR

```
sudo easy_install redis
```

If you already installed it, then check

```
import redis
print(redis.__file__)
```

And check whether it is imported from correct package.

Also check whether any `redis.py` or `redis.pyc` is existing in your current folder which may cause overriding the package.If yes, rename it and restart `interpreter`